# How to reconnect an Actiontec PK5000 router in C#?

Tags: c#, router

I got a DSL router Actiontec PK5000.

I need it to reboot it using C#.

It does have an interface on 192.168.0.1 that I can access from the webbrowser.

That interface has a "reconnection" tab.

That tab has some javascript that I have to trigger on page load.

But when I trigger it prompt pops out asking me to hit "Continue".

And I'm not sure how to click that.

I'm pretty sure there should be some easier way to reboot it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Javascript? HTML? Why javascript _or_ HTML in the tags? Fixed that for you.

Comment: Go to the [JDownloader community forum](http://board.jdownloader.org/) and search for the model name of your modem. If there is a solution to the problem, there will be some mention of it there, so you could study it to get ideas from it. (Or you could keep JDownloader always running so that you can click its "Reset my modem" button when you need it.)

Comment: If you figured it out, you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fugured it out. Just sent a C# POST request to the modem through this table. Here's the code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var uriString = "http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/webcm";
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                NameValueCollection myNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
                myNameValueCollection.Add("getpage", "../html/status_hide.html");
                myNameValueCollection.Add("var:opt", "0");
                myNameValueCollection.Add("logic:command/kill_ppp", "");
                myNameValueCollection.Add("encaps0:pppoa:command/stop", "1");
                byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadValues(uriString, myNameValueCollection);
                log("Failed to update mail date creation, function UpdateMailDateCreation. MySQL error:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```